# Is Mjolnir either sentient, or semi-sentient?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, mjolnir

In his comment on [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92116/are-there-clear-cut-rules-about-what-constitutes-lifting-mjolnir) far inferior question, Richard stated that Mjolnir appears to be at least semi-sentient.  Based on my hazy recollections of reading my brother's Thor comics when I was little, I am inclined to agree.

What I'm talking about is related to the restrictions on who can lift/wield Mjolnir - does Mjolnir follow a previously determined set of rules, or is it controlled by Odin, or does Mjolnir itself make decisions about who can do what with it, based on the specific circumstances in which it finds itself?  Is it obeying orders, or is it choosing the best course of action in every situation?

Does Mjolnir have some degree of a mind of its own?  Is it truly sentient, or at least semi-sentient?

Comment: We know it has "opinions" about, or at least reactions to, its wielders: it has been shown to perform much more complex tasks easily in service to the new female Thor, something which Odinson (the previous male Thor) seems baffled by.  So, even if not sentient, certainly reactive.

Comment: So my response to Richard, that Mjolnir might not like being told what to do, and allows other characters to use it against Thor to get a bit of revenge, wasn't entirely off base?  Now I wish I hadn't deleted the comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Mjolnir is a magical weapon. In myths and legends, magical weapons were often thought to have magical abilities without necessarily having self-awareness. Like any weapon, each user of said weapon will develop techniques and skills with that weapon, different from any other based on their strengths and limitations. Mjolnir responds differently because Jane Foster is different from the Odinson.

- Mjolnir in use by Thor Odinson is clearly a weapon of brute power. Capable of casually destroying a mountain range Thor prides himself on his strength and battle prowess.Thus Mjolnir is a smiting weapon best unleashed with full strength, able to tear through the Odinson's enemies. With Mjolnir, Thor Odinson, kills those who believe they cannot BE killed.

In the images below, an alien race called the Builders plan on destroying the Earth and all life upon it. A species of incredible individual and technological might, they believe the Avengers have arrived to surrender to them.

- In the panel before this Thor says a prayer and appears to "speak" to Mjolnir before throwing the weapon toward the sun. It might appear to a casual user that Thor is talking to an intelligent, self-aware weapon.
- But we also know Mjolnir "responds" to Thor's will, spoken or unspoken. So the prayer may be for Odin's guidance, that he be making the correct choice in defying the Builders with the fate of the Earth in the balance.

[image]

When the Builder tells Thor, his species plans on destroying the Earth as an object lesson and knocks the Thunder God to his knees, Mjolnir responds to his will by circling the sun and returning with a little extra "slingshot effect" on it.

[image]

Thus, the immortal, unable to be killed, trash-talking Builder is mortally wounded, by Thor and Mjolnir in a physical feat, only the Odinson could accomplish.

[image]

[image]

- Mjolnir with Jane Foster as Thor, is a more nuanced weapon. While she may have the Power of Thor, she does not have his natural physical gifts of his Earth-mother's additional strength. Thor is the strongest Asgardian due to his dual heritage. Thus she does not use the hammer the same way the Odinson does. It is more nimble, it is quicker, it responds to her touch because it is a lighter one.

[image]

*In this battle against the Destroyer, the Destroyer is holding on to Mjolnir (as Odin points out, it isn't truly lifting Mjolnir, more like one weapon holding another, no worthiness required) since Thor cannot take Mjolnir back, she uses her control of it to bash the Destroyer all over the landscape, since it refuses to let go of the hammer.*

The weapon may not need sentience to be able to do these things. It may simply be responsive to a different touch because the user is working with her strengths and limitations.

- She is not the Odinson, she does not have his gifts, so she works within her limitations, using her stronger connection to Mjolnir to greater facility because she needs to. To be fair to the Odinson, when he was pushed to his limits he too could be fairly creative with Mjolnir (see above example)
- Indeed, it may be her humanity which causes her to consider the hammer differently. To Thor Odinson, Mjolnir was little more than a favored weapon, powerful, devastating but ultimately secondary to the hand of its wielder.
- To Jane Foster's Thor, her chance to use Mjolnir, a weapon she has watched in the hands of a man/god she nearly married, loved dearly and then left behind, it has become an object of veneration.
- Indeed, she believes the weapon has chosen her. But her human perspective may make her believe the weapon is more sentient and less reactive. She has very limited knowledge of the magic/technology of Asgard and can only work from her intuitions.

[image]

- Mjolnir is a magical device which has not only forestalled her inevitable descent into cancer and death, but given her another chance at godhood. It may simply be responding to her elation at being alive. It doesn't necessarily need to be self-aware to do that.